# NotEnoughReplicasException: Messages are rejected since there are fewer in-sync replicas than required

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

l have 5 kafka broker. And in my producer app, my configs is like below:
Interesting part is that, after getting this exception 2 times, in third time message is producing to topic.

```
spring:
  kafka:
    streams:
      replication-factor: 3
    properties:
      min.insync.replicas: 2
    producer:
      acks: "all"
      batch-size: 1
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      value-serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
      compression-type: "lz4"
      retries: 2
      properties:
        linger.ms: 1
        request:
          timeout:
            ms: 60000
```

So, l tried to assign different count for replication-factor and min.insync.replicas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`min.insync.replicas` and `replication.factor` are both **Topic Configs**, not a Kafka (Streams) client property.

From Spring Kafka , you can use `@Bean NewTopic` to define Kafka topic resources with their configurations.

---

Your error probably went away because the cluster had healed itself, while your app was retrying the request. You should look at the broker server logs rather than your app's.

Comment: thank you, it solved my problem. l set replica count to 3 and min.insync.replica value to 2. After fixing configurations and refreshing topic it worked perfectly. Thanks, again